# Good or Bad - Use a constructor to initialize model from a remote webservice

Tags: java, object, constructor

I would like know if it good or bad to initialize my model by a request to a webservices or is it better to use an another public method called after the constructor

For example:

```
class Model {
    ModelData data;

    Model(Integer model_id) {
       data = Request.getDataFromWebServices(model_id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally a good aproach to use as constructor args parameters that are **required** for the class to be functional (instead of using setters).
So in your case if `model_id` is mandatory for `Model` to work, it is correct you have it there.
Now you use `model_id` to do a remote method call.
Remote method calls can take more time to execute, making `Model` taking more time to initialize and could fail e.g. due to network reasons.
If the api covers any exception either coming from network layer or from the actual processing and returning a good value to initialize the `Model` then IMHO it should be ok as it is.
Just document the class as taking more time to initialize due to network access

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the use in constructor or anywhere else, the problem is using a global variable. It would be much better to pass `request` by instance to show the dependency in the API of Model:

```
class Model {
  final ModelData data;

  Model(Request request, int model_id) {
    data = request.getDataFromWebServices(model_id);
  }
}
```

or create by a more descriptive factory method:

```
class Model {
  static Model createModelFromWebServices(Request request, int model_id) {
    return new Model(request.getDataFromWebServices(model_id));
  }

  final ModelData data;

  Model(ModelData data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

I used the primitive `int` instead of `Integer` because I wanted to shaw that `null` is not a valid value for `model_id`.

Comment: +1 Because i don't have thinking about the problem with "Request". But it's always possible to extend Model with a ModelRequest, no?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is highly dependent on your individual circumstance.

I personally would probably make the constructor private, and expose a public static method called something like "CreateModelFromService" to make it clear to anyone else using my class that there is a larger-than-normal chance the method might fail due to things like network connectivity, etc. I typically wouldn't expect such an error when instantiating a *seemingly* non-network-related class.

Just my $0.02

Answer (score 0):

Depends where this component will be used. Most programmers expect constructors to complete fairly quickly so doing network operations may not be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Both initializing on instantiation and later are valid.  The real questions are what restrictions are you dealing with, what might fail at some point, when will you need to access the state and will you be able to work with a potential delay waiting until you need to access the state to compute the state.   Neither is right or wrong unless your situation calls for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to unit test something that requires an instance of one of your model classes. How will you create this instance without the webservice?

It might be worth considering a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) to create model instances using a webservice instead. This separates your model from the specific assembly mechanism:

```
class Model {
    Model(ModelData data) { ... }
}

class ModelFactory {
    private Request request;

    Model create(Integer modelId) { 
        return new Model(request.getDataFromWebServices(modelId));
    }    
}
```

Comment: -1 Factory is not the appropriate pattern to resolve this problem.